# Jquery sortable element should move only up-down not left or right

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using jquery sortable function for Li within a Ul tag, when i am dragging and dropping elements within ul, then i wanting that it can not be dragged left or right within ul. it should be dragged only up and down.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

[Try this:](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Sortable#option-axis)

`$( ".selector" ).sortable({ axis: 'y' });`

From the docs:

> If defined, the items can be dragged only horizontally or vertically.
>   Possible values:'x', 'y'.